# llenar un div con una tabla o un mensaje a partir de dos select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, endpoint

estoy sufriendo un poco con un desafio:

> El desafio consta de diseñar una pagina web la cual se comunique con
>   tres endpoints para tomar datos de alumnos. El proyecto debe constar
>   de una caja de selección donde se muestren los nombres y apellidos de
>   cada alumno, debe existir otra caja de selección que liste las
>   carreras de un alumno elegido en el selector anterior. Este elemento
>   debe cargarse dinámicamente con los datos que correspondan cada vez
>   que se cambie un alumno de la primer caja de selección.
>
> Al seleccionar una carrera del alumno debe aparecer una tabla que
>   contenga prioritariamente el nombre de las materias cursadas en esa
>   carrera y el ultimo año en que se curso. Ej.: Un alumno que cursa la
>   carrera de ANALISTA DE SISTEMAS DE COMPUTACION puede cursar la materia
>   PROGRAMACION I en el 2015, pero recursarla en el 2017. En ese caso se
>   tiene que mostrar 2017 en la columna año. Si el alumno no curso
>   ninguna materia de la carrera seleccionada en vez de la tabla debe
>   mostrarse un mensaje que muestre el texto “El alumno no curso materias
>   en esta carrera”.

mi problema es que no se me ocurre como mostrar el mensaje o la tabla con sus respectivos encabezados

este es mi html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Prueba técnica</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container">
        <form class="" action="index.html" method="get">
          <div class="row">
            <select class="form-control form-control-lg col-sm-12 col-md-5" id="alumnos">
              <option selected disabled>Seleccione un alumno</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control form-control-lg col-sm-12 col-md-5" id="carreras">
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="sin-materias">
          <table class="table materias">
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

</html>
```

y este es mi codigo jquery/javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var alumnos = [];
  var carreras = [];
  var materias = [];

$.getJSON("https://5dfa8e7e38678a00145fa4b0.mockapi.io/api/v1/Alumnos", function(arrayAlumnos){
  $.each(arrayAlumnos, function(indice, objeto){
    $("#alumnos").append('<option value="' + objeto.numDoc + '">'  + objeto.apellido + ', ' + objeto.nombre + '</option>');
  });
  alumnos = arrayAlumnos;
  console.log(alumnos);
});


$.getJSON("http://5dfa8e7e38678a00145fa4b0.mockapi.io/api/v1/Carreras", function(arrayCarreras){

  carreras = arrayCarreras;
  console.log(carreras);
  });

  $.getJSON("http://5dfa8e7e38678a00145fa4b0.mockapi.io/api/v1/Materias", function(arrayMaterias){
    materias = arrayMaterias;
    console.log(materias);
    });

  var llenarCarreras = function(){
    var seleccion = $("#alumnos").val();
    $("#carreras").empty();
    $.each(carreras, function(indice, objeto){
      var documentoAlumno = seleccion.trim();
      var documentoCarrera = objeto.numDoc.trim();
      if (documentoAlumno == documentoCarrera) {
        $("#carreras").append('<option value="' + objeto.idCarrera + '">'  + objeto.descripcion + '</option>');
      }
    });
  }
  $("#alumnos").change(llenarCarreras);

  var llenarMaterias = function(){
    var seleccionAlumno = $("#alumnos").val();
    var seleccionCarrera = $("#carreras").val();
    $(".materias").empty();
    $.each(materias, function(indice, objeto){
      var documentoAlumno = seleccionAlumno.trim();
      var documentoMateria = objeto.numDoc.trim();
      if (documentoAlumno == documentoMateria && objeto.idCarrera==seleccionCarrera) {
        $(".materias").
        append('<tr><td>' + objeto.idMateria + '</td><td>' + objeto.descripcion + '</td><td>' + objeto.añoCurso + '</td></tr>');
      }
    });
  }
  $("#carreras").change(llenarMaterias);


});
```

Comment: Esto no me queda claro: *Un alumno que cursa la carrera de ANALISTA DE SISTEMAS DE COMPUTACION puede cursar la materia PROGRAMACION I en el 2015, pero recursarla en el 2017.* Imagino que para un alumno ciertas materias se repetirían, pero en años distintos ¿es así? En ese caso, ¿hay que mostrar únicamente la que cursó en el año más reciente? Dado que se trata de un ejercicio, ¿se podría aplicar técnicas cualesquiera, como funciones para organizar el JSON por una determinada clave, etc.?

Comment: @A.Cedano si, se deberia mostrar la que curso en el año mas reciente... con respecto a organizar el json no creo que sea posible, al menos en la consigna no lo especifica pero por ejemplo lo que si hice fue hacerle un trim a los numDoc porque sino no me genera las coincidencias al tener espacios vacios

Comment: Intenté ver un poco el JSON pero es complicado porque viene con caracteres raros que dificultan el análisis, pero me parece que para un alumno pueden haber varios objetos JSON con la misma materia pero con años distintos ¿es así? Si es así, dado que es un ejercicio, tienes que decir qué te está permitido para obtener solamente el del último año.